# jqGrid:: onclicking each row after editing another, saves the content but not restoring the edited row

Tags: jqgrid, save, inline, edit, restore

the purpose is that after editing the text area in a line, and clicking on another row, the first one should get saved and the row should be restored.  The code works till saving the record, but not restoring the edited row after saving.. Please help me to rectify the issue.

```
 <? 
if(isset($_GET)){
    $startDate = $_GET['start_date'];
    $endDate   = $_GET['end_date'];
    $type      = $_GET['type'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../js/jqgrid/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../js/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/powertip/jquery.powertip.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqgrid/js/jquery1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/powertip/jquery.powertip-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    </script>
    <script src="../js/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        .ratingDetails{
            font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#FFF;padding-left:2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="rowed2"></table>
    <div id="prowed2"></div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
            var lastSel;
            jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({ 
                url:'feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php?start_date=<?=$startDate?>&end_date=<?=$endDate?>&type=<?=$type?>',

                datatype: "json",
                height:"auto",
                colNames:['Booking<br>Id','City','Customer name','Trip dates','Local Office','Rating','Action Taken','Status','Action'],

                colModel:[
                    {name:'booking_id',index:'booking_id', width:45,align:"center",hidden:false,key: true},// key: true - to get the id value in POST
                    {name:'pick_city',index:'pick_city', width:90,align:"left"},
                    {name:'actual_name',index:'add_driver_number', width:130,align:"left",sortable:true},
                    {name:'tripdates',index:'tripdates', width:80,align:"center",sortable:false},
                    {name:'office_name',index:'office_name', width:150,align:"left",sortable:true},     
                    {name:'rating_status',index:'rating_status', width:70,align:"center",sortable:true,title: false},
                    {name:'action_taken',index:'action_taken', width:220,align:"left",sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:'textarea',editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"35"}},
                    {name:'img_action_status',index:'img_action_status', width:40,align:"center",sortable:true},    
                    {name:'act',index:'act',width:100,align:'center',sortable:false}        
                ],
                rowNum:15, 
                rowList:[15,25,50], 
                pager: '#prowed2', 
                sortname: 'driver_name', 
                viewrecords: true, 
                sortorder: "asc", 
                subGrid : true, 
                subGridUrl: 'feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php?booking=424519', 
                subGridModel: [{
                        name:['Booked on','Trip Type/ Amount','Driver Details','Local Office Phone','Essential Feedbacks','Other Feedbacks'],
                        width: [90,90,130,100,160,200]}
                ],

                onSelectRow: 
                    function(id){ 
                        //alert(lastSel+"-hi-"+id);
                        if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
                            if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',lastSel);
                                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
                                //jQuery("#rowed2").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
                            }
                            lastSel = id;
                         } 
                        jQuery(this).jqGrid('resetSelection'); 
                        jQuery(this).editRow(id, true); 
                    },      
                editurl: "feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php", 
                caption:"Edit Feedback Details",
            }); 

            // icons in pagination frame bottom
            jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid','#prowed2',{ add: false, edit: true,save: true, del: false, reload: true});


            jQuery.fn.editRow = function(param) {
                var rowid      = param;
                var booking_id = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid ('getCell', param, 'booking_id');

                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('editRow',rowid, { 
                        keys : true, 
                        oneditfunc: function() {
                        }
                    });
            };

            jQuery.fn.saveRow = function(param) {
                var rowid = param;
                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',rowid, { 
                        successfunc: function(response) {
                                        //obj = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
                                        //$.jgrid.info_dialog('Status','<div class="ui-state-successr"><br>'+obj.responseText +'<br></div>', $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'center'}); 
                                        return true; 
                                      },
                        url : "feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php",
                        mtype : "POST",
                    });
            };

            jQuery.fn.restoreRow = function(param) {
                var rowid = param;
                alert("rstore-"+rowid);
                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('restoreRow',rowid, { 
                    afterrestorefunc : function( response ) {
                        alert("aaaa");
                        obj = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
                        $.jgrid.info_dialog('Status','<div class="ui-state-successr"><br>'+obj.responseText +'<br></div>', $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'center'}); 
                        return true; 
                    }
                });
            };

        })

            function closeAction(bkId){
                if(confirm("Are you sure to close the action?")){
                    //Ok button pressed...
                    $.post('feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php?action=close',{booking_id: bkId},
                        function(response){
                            alert(response.responseText); 
                            $("#rowed2").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
                            return true;
                        },
                        "json"
                    );
                }
            }
            // Function to display rating crieteria values as a tooltip on mouseover of Rating caption
            function showRatingDetailsToolTip(id) {
                $('#rating'+id).data('powertiptarget', 'tooltip'+id);
                $('#rating'+id).powerTip({placement: 'e',smartPlacement: true,mouseOnToPopup: true});

            }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Again.. given below a rectified code.. here also, the previous row not getting back from edit mode on clicking next row. Can you tell me the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../js/jqgrid/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../js/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqgrid/js/jquery1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    </script>
    <script src="../js/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="rowed2"></table>
    <div id="prowed2"></div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
            var lastSel;
            jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({ 
                url:'feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php?start_date=<?=$startDate?>&end_date=<?=$endDate?>&type=<?=$type?>', 
                datatype: "json",
                height:"auto",
                colNames:['Booking<br>Id','City','Customer name','Trip dates','Local Office','Rating','Action Taken','Status','Action'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'booking_id',index:'booking_id', width:45,align:"center",hidden:false,key: true},// key: true - to get the id value in POST
                    {name:'pick_city',index:'pick_city', width:90,align:"left"},
                    {name:'actual_name',index:'add_driver_number', width:130,align:"left",sortable:true,editable:true,edittype:'text'},
                    {name:'tripdates',index:'tripdates', width:80,align:"center",sortable:false},
                    {name:'office_name',index:'office_name', width:150,align:"left",sortable:true},     
                    {name:'rating_status',index:'rating_status', width:70,align:"center",sortable:true,title: false},
                    {name:'action_taken',index:'action_taken', width:220,align:"left",sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:'textarea',editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"35"}},
                    {name:'img_action_status',index:'img_action_status', width:40,align:"center",sortable:true},    
                    {name:'act',index:'act',width:100,align:'center',sortable:false}        
                ],
                rowNum:15, 
                rowList:[15,25,50], 
                pager: '#prowed2', 
                sortname: 'booking_id', 
                viewrecords: true, 
                sortorder: "asc", 

                onSelectRow: 
                    function(id){ 
                        if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
                            if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',lastSel,{url : "feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php",mtype : "POST"});
                                jQuery(this).jqGrid('editRow',lastSel, false);
                            }
                            lastSel = id;
                         } 
                        jQuery(this).jqGrid('editRow',id, true);
                    }, 

                editurl: "feedbacks_bookings_rated_pagination.php", 
                caption:"Edit Feedback Details",
            }); 

            // icons in pagination frame bottom
            jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid','#prowed2',{ add: false, edit: false,save: false, del: false, reload: true});
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

=====================

At last I could find the real problem.

It is not with the content of 'action_taken' field, but with the just previous field. In that I put a table inside a hidden DIV under the actual content, used for a tooltip content.

What happens is that after editing the action_taken field in next column and the server response is received, the edited content of 'action_taken' field was set to the content and title of the first TD of this table in previous column. Also, the edited column does not return from edit mode. If I remove the table from previous column, everything works ok. I tried with different id/style class for the table, but no change. What could be the problem? The table structure in previous column causing the issue is given below.

```
<table id='ratingdata32380' width='189' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#000000' bgcolor='#4f9de2'>
<tr><td align='left' valign='middle' class='ratingDetails'>Was On Time?</td><td align='center' valign='middle' class='ratingDetails'>aaaa</td></tr>
</table>
```

The class 'ratingDetails' is nothing but just the font definition.
.ratingDetails{font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#FFF;padding-left:2px;}

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You should decide which behavior should have your grid. You you want save the data from the previously editing row then you should call `saveRow`. If you want to discard the current changes and to restore the previous one you should call `restoreRow`. Calling of `restoreRow` **after** `saveRow` like you do currently inside of `onSelectRow` callback has no sense.

So if I understand correctly what you want to implement you should *remove* the line with `saveRow` which is before calling of `restoreRow`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Let me clarify it.  I called 'restoreRow' after saving, only because that the text area displayed for editing is still there even after saving, and the row does not go back to normal appearance after saving. That is, when clicking each row, it turn to editmode and the column shows a text area and no previous row return to original stage with updated value. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: @JustineThomas: I found in your code that you replace `jQuery.fn.editRow` for example. It's wrong! Moreover you use `jQuery.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true`. So you can't use functions in the form `jQuery(this).editRow(id, true);` (see the code of `onSelectRow` callback). You have to use `jQuery(this).jqGrid("editRow", id, true);`. I can continue... Sorry but about the half of your current code is *absolutely wrong*. I am not wonder then call `jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('saveRow',lastSel)` is not work. You should use Fiddler, Firebug or other tool to verify how saving work.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your valuable comments.  I am new to JQGrid, and could not find a real documentation containing the full routines of possible operations. I appreciate if you can help me by quickly rewriting the wrong section so that it will be a good reference point as well for me.

Comment: @JustineThomas: You are welcome! First of all I don't use PHP. The second: you should first remove all unneeded parts from your code: functions `closeAction` and `showRatingDetailsToolTip` which will be not used here, remove redefinition of `jQuery.fn.editRow`, `jQuery.fn.saveRow` and `jQuery.fn.restoreRow`, change `jQuery(this).editRow(id, true)` to `jQuery(this).jqGrid("editRow", id, true)`, remove call of `restoreRow` and `resetSelection`. Then you should use Fiddler or Firebug to verify what will be send to the server on saving of rows and how the response looks like.

Comment: is there a good documentation with working samples for new legacy API?

Comment: a rectified code is added above.  can you look into it, Oleg please?

Comment: @JustineThomas: I can't recommend you any documentation other as [the standard](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs). The code can be improved and simplified, but the current one should work. Do you verified the HTTP traffic to and from the server ([Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), "Network" tab of Developer Tools of IE: press F12 to start etc)? What will be sent to the server on the saving of row and what how the response looks like?

Comment: firebug sys:

Parameters:- 
action_taken: test2
actual_name: test
id: 424230
oper: edit

'test' & 'test2' are the values i entered which passed into the server on POST. this was working with previous code as well. Only problem is that, after editing this value in the row X, if I click on row Y, the values in row X should be saved and its edit mode should be closed to look like a normal row, and row Y should be in edit mode. This is not happening. Means, on clicking row Y, still row X is appearing in edit mode even after its content is saved. how to solve this problem? also response text is OK

Comment: @JustineThomas: Sorry, but I have to ask at the third time: it's important to know the **full** response from the server too. Moreover one clear error in your current code is the line **`jQuery(this).jqGrid('editRow',lastSel, false);`** after `saveRow`. Why you permanently include some coll after saving of the row? You should just save `lastSel` row using `saveRow` and start editing of new row (`id`) using `editRow` inside of `onSelectRow`. I recommend you additionally use `jQuery(this)` instead of `jQuery("#rowed2")` inside of all callbacks (see `onSelectRow`) and add `gridview: true` option.

Comment: included the row - jQuery(this).jqGrid('editRow',lastSel, false); after saveRow only because of to see if disabling editmode of previous row will work in this way. Removed it and applied changes as per your suggestions. the response received is  {"responseText":"Action comment recorded"}  which is a message I am sending from server script after updating DB.  what do you think?

Comment: got a clue !!..  the field '{name:'action_taken',index:'action_taken',...' causes the problem.  if it is marked not editable and any other to be editable, it works perfectly..  what is the issue with this line?

Comment: @JustineThomas: Sorry, but the goal of stackoverflow is sharing of common problems as questions and the solutions as answers. It's not a help forum. Changing of 'action_taken' to non-editable as solution of your problem can mean clear bug in your server code. As I wrote  **full** response from the server I mean really full HTTP response inclusive HTTP status code which is extremely important for jQuery.ajax requests. [The status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) should have some error value (>=400). Returning texts `responseText` has no sense.

Comment: Hi, this is the server response header

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2013 17:49:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.3.14 mod_perl/2.0.6 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 64
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: one strange thing is that after saving, the previous row's editable field is containing a text content as follows

<textarea rows="3" cols="35" id="387573_action_taken" name="action_taken" role="textbox" multiline="true" class="editable"></textarea>

Comment: found the problem and posted the details above. please have look into it and share your thoughts. Thanks...